# Verb meaning to be earlier (than expected)

Tags: single-word-requests

Given the sentence:

> As the policy timeline continues to _________, we expect the industry
>   to pick up momentum.

This phrase is used a lot in my writing and I have already exhausted some of the more obvious choices like "accelerate." I also thought "advance" might work here, but I don't think it conveys the *earlier than expected* implication.

Comment: "shift to the left" is typical jargon for moving the elements of a timeline to be earlier than originally planned.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Not to be confused with a "jump to the left."    Would it help you to flip it around for sentence variety? "As the timeline gains momentum, we expect the industry to mirror this pace." Or "We expect the industry to pick up speed in respect to the advanced timeline."

Comment: The timeline itself (as a physical or logical representation, where the length of a line indicates duration), **shrinks** or **decreases**. But, as with the earlier comments, it's not clear if this is the type of thing you're looking for.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[Precede](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=PYFSXeSJCJGwvgSi3pTwCw&q=precede%20meaning&oq=&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-hp.1.1.41j41i70i249j41j41i13j41j41i67i70i249j41i10j41i22i29i30.0.0..2221...0.0..0.0.0.......0...........8.RINAKwBE9j8):

come before (something) in time.

> As the policy timeline continues to **precede**, we expect the
>   industry to pick up momentum.

Comment: _Precede_ is almost always a transitive verb. In fact, only the American Heritage Dictionary lists an intransitive use, and then it does not provide an example. The suggested use in this answer looks ungrammatical, and I haven't been able to find a similar use in any of the commonly available corpora.

Answer (score 2):

*As the policy timeline continues to **hasten**, we expect the industry to pick up momentum.*

**Hasten**

> to cause to hasten; accelerate

*to hasten someone from a room*;  *to hasten the arrival of a happier time.*

[Dictionary.com]

Answer (score 0):

How about:

As the policy timeline continues to ***encroach***, we expect the industry to pick up momentum.

Answer (score -1):

**To be prescient**

Prescient means ‘showing up before it is supposed to, ‘ahead of its time’, or ‘seen before it happened’.

‘As the policy timeline continues to be prescient, we expect the industry to pick up momentum.’

You could also use ‘be ahead of schedule’.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prescient